# Nested LINQ to get summary or survey with the best performance

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance, linq

I have a database that contain 3 table that is

- survey table
- survey question table (link with survey id)
- survey question log table (link with survey question id)

Since my survey are very flexible that support survey with many style ( data survey to generate graph, to analyze or predict something )

That's why, I want to get all the question log that relate to the specific survey to process...

so I wonder what is the best performance way to query?

I am not familiar with LINQ much, from my small brain, I can think only 3 ways

---

1 NESTED FROM (from inside from)

however, I know that this will be the bad-dest thing to do in normal SQL, but what about LINQ? is it a good choice?
Advantage: minimum transfer data, the survey table and survey question table (1 per each)
Disadvantage: it will take query = survey x survey_question x survey_question_log times

```
from sv in SURVEYs
where sv.PROJECT_ID == 6 &&
        sv.ACTIVE == 1
select new {sv, sq = (from sq in SURVEY_QUESTIONs
                        where sq.SURVEY_ID == sv.ID
                        select new { sq, sql = (
                                    from sql in SURVEY_QUESTION_LOGs
                                    where sql.SURVEY_QUESTION_ID == sq.ID
                                    select new { sql }) })}
```

---

2 SINGLE QUERY ( with left join )

if in normal SQL, I think this is the best way
Advantage: 1 query, safe database server
Disadvantage: alot of transfer data, it will get alot of useless data ( alot of duplicate survey data & survey question data)

```
from sv in SURVEYs

join svq in SURVEY_QUESTIONs
on sv.ID equals svq.SURVEY_ID into ssvq
from subsvq in ssvq.DefaultIfEmpty()

join svql in SURVEY_QUESTION_LOGs
on subsvq.ID equals svql.SURVEY_QUESTION_ID into ssvql
from subsvql in ssvql.DefaultIfEmpty()

where sv.PROJECT_ID == 6 &&
sv.ACTIVE == 1
select new { sv, subsvq, subsvql }
```

---

3 EXTERNAL QUERY (get data from database and query by yourself)
I also think of query data out from 3 tables, and use advantage of LINQ to query by using the server CPU... is it also be considered?
advantage: query 3 times (survey, survey_question, survey_question_log)
disadvantage: no-idea, not sure which one will be faster? database + sql? server + linq?

```
from sv in SURVEYs select sv;
from svq in SURVEY_QUESTIONs select svq;
from svql in SURVEY_QUESTION_LOGs select svql;

//foreach LINQ here
//may be as same as CASE 1, but do in SERVER here
```

---

any other case is very welcome!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best performance that you have is your third option.

The database server is designed to return data efficiently. 
I think that if you make stored procedures is better why the stored procedures is compiled and it will be taken into account in the execution plain.

All this with linq you will have a good performance.

Database + Stored Proedures
Maybe you don't need use to the linq.

You always must think in the data volume to manage.